# Emulating Polygon Neighbors tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0 SP5.

[image]

Have a set of 4000 polygons (featureclass A) and I'd like to summarise the values of the polygons (featureclass B) which touch the boundaries of these polygons (ie. those which neighbour A). The Summary statistics should include values in A (the field that I'd like to summarise is common to both featureclasses).

There is a tool in 10.1 and above called 'Polygon Neighbors' which would do exactly what I need, but that's not available in 10.0: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/polygon-neighbors.htm

Is there a way to do this in 10.0?

Dissolving B polygons and using summarising statistics within this tool  will not work because some of the B polygons share a boundary with more than one A polygon. I need a separate summary for each A polygon.

This is not a duplicate question. The question which was marked as 'the same' as this asks where the 'Polygon Neighbors' tool is in 10.0. I realise that this tool isn't available in 10.0, I am asking how to produce the same output as this tool.

Comment: Others agreed with you that this was not a duplicate question but I think it distills to the same question of "How to determine polygon neighbors at 10.0?"  I actually think the two questions should be merged. In any event, now that you are aware of the "similar" question I think you should include a link to it within yours.